# Serializing JSON with varing datatype with the same variable

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying out Opensignal API and have run into a wall when trying to use Jackson 2.0 to serialize the result. The networkRank can be an array or it can be a string

How could I set Jackson to serialize JSON properly, like if it's a string, save it to this `String networkRank` attribute else save it to `List <NetworkRank> = new ArrayList<NetworkRank>()`

These are result of their api: (Check out networkRank below)

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2",
    "latitude": "14.55669",
    "longitude": "121.370119",
    "distance": "10",
    "network_type": "10",
    "perMinuteCurrent": 0,
    "perMinuteLimit": 10,
    "perMonthCurrent": 7,
    "perMonthLimit": 2000,
    "networkRank": "No results for this area"   
}
```

and

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2",
    "latitude": "14.55669",
    "longitude": "121.370119",
    "distance": "10",
    "network_type": "10",
    "perMinuteCurrent": 0,
    "perMinuteLimit": 10,
    "perMonthCurrent": 7,
    "perMonthLimit": 2000,
    "networkRank": [
         {
         "networkName": "T-Mobile",
         "networkId": "310260",
  "type3G": {
    "networkName": "T-Mobile",
    "networkId": "310260",
    "networkType": "3",
    "averageRssiAsu": "10.934899",
    "averageRssiDb": "-91.130203",
    "sampleSizeRSSI": "437532",
    "downloadSpeed": "4532.8305",
    "uploadSpeed": "1124.9649",
    "pingTime": "148.8205",
    "reliability": "94.5944170771741"
  },
  "type4G": {
    "networkName": "EE",
    "networkId": "23430",
    "networkType": "4",
    "averageRsrpAsu": "33.865632",
    "averageRsrpDb": "-106.134368",
    "sampleSizeRSRP": "284041",
    "downloadSpeed": "9851.1000",
    "uploadSpeed": "4377.3200",
    "pingTime": "87.0000",
    "reliability": "96.2113095238094"
     }
   }
  ]  
}
```

Comment: What is the class for serialization look likes? Do you mean there is a `Object` field  of `networkRank` that can be either a `String` or `List <NetworkRank>`?

Comment: Hi Wilson, the web service results in array of network rank if network signal exists, else it send no network signal found as string. So the same field becomes a string or an array.

Comment: Sounds you need to deserialize the JSON response into a class object? If that is the case, what the class for deserialization you look like? or any class structure is welcome as long as there is a same field to store a string or an array after deserialization?

Comment: The latter, any class structure as long as there is a same field to store a string or and array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to use a same field for either a json string or a array is probably to use a `Object` field. This solution do not need a custom serializer and deserializer. Following is an example class with Jackson annotation:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public class NetworkStatistics {

    private String apiVersion;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;
    private String distance;
    @JsonProperty("network_type")
    private String networkType;
    private int perMinuteCurrent;
    private int perMinuteLimit;
    private int perMonthCurrent;
    private int perMonthLimit;
    private Object networkRank;

    public NetworkStatistics() {
    }

    // getters
}
```

Following is an example to deserialize a json string of the api response into `NetworkStatistics` instance:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
NetworkStatistics networkStatistics = mapper.readValue(json, NetworkStatistics.class);
```

and an example to serialize `NetworkStatistics` instance into json String:

```
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(networkStatistics))
```

If `networkRank` in json is a string value, the instance field after deserialization will be a `String` field. If it is a json array, the instance field will be a `java.util.ArrayList` field.

Hope this can help.

Comment: It works! Thanks! If I may ask, how would the the getter code look like so that I won't have to use casting when getting the data? Or should I have 2 getter methods intead?

Comment: You can have 2 more getter methods like `getNetworkRankAsString()` and `getNetworkRankAsList()` to return a `String` and a `List` respectively. If most of time you work with a `List`, it will be useful to return a empty list from `getNetworkRankAsList()` if `networkRank` is a string (by using `instanceof`).